# importing to sharepoint via an xml file?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, import

When I take a look at the output file of the `stsadm -o export` command, I can see a "simple" xml file that takes the full content of a site.

Is it safe to reuse such an xml file to import data through `stsadm -o import` command ?

I mean, can I generate an xml file that respect the SP format to inject data to SP ?

something like this :

```
<SPObject Id="2efe1c96-cf29-4ade-9f5f-f73451f07576" ObjectType="SPListItem" ParentId="fa5afbc9-0e48-4bde-bceb-a65bcf3fe862" ParentWebId="f0bc765d-1b02-4c03-b59d-5d0ab85a0db5" ParentWebUrl="/aide" Url="/aide/Pages Wiki/Colonne Statut.aspx">
    <ListItem 
    FileUrl="Pages Wiki/Colonne Statut.aspx" 
    DocType="File" 
    ParentFolderId="0f70edd9-1b3d-48a9-b7cc-de21413e2158" 
    Id="2efe1c96-cf29-4ade-9f5f-f73451f07576" 
    ParentWebId="f0bc765d-1b02-4c03-b59d-5d0ab85a0db5" 
    ParentListId="fa5afbc9-0e48-4bde-bceb-a65bcf3fe862" 

    IntId="9"
    DocId="7ab00ce5-cff2-458b-b353-c5f27710b1f7"
    Version="1.0"
    ContentTypeId="0x01010800EC194E065D111C41960C31AE6200DFB2"
    Author="1" 
    ModifiedBy="1" 
    TimeLastModified="2010-07-23T15:03:27"
    TimeCreated="2010-07-23T15:03:27" ModerationStatus="Approved">
        <Fields>
            <Field Name="_ModerationComments" FieldId="34ad21eb-75bd-4544-8c73-0e08330291fe" />
            <Field Name="Modified_x0020_By" FieldId="822c78e3-1ea9-4943-b449-57863ad33ca9" />
            <Field Name="Created_x0020_By" FieldId="4dd7e525-8d6b-4cb4-9d3e-44ee25f973eb" />

            <Field Name="_SourceUrl" FieldId="c63a459d-54ba-4ab7-933a-dcf1c6fadec2" />

            <Field Name="MyField" Value="MyVal" />
        </Fields>        
    </ListItem>
</SPObject>
```

My actual goal is to populate a few list from an xml export of a custom master application, in an ETL way.

Comment: I would not recommend the use of stsadm -o import/export for simple data ETL tasks. This command often falls over if you don't run as the SharePoint Install service account, which has dangerously high privileges for an ETL load.

Comment: @JamesLove: do you know actually what is the requirement to import datas ?

Comment: You need GUIDs for key properties required for the object model to construct the elements to be written. This will be extremely long and tedious to do. You're far safer either drumming up an intermediate application using Lists Webservice, or the Client Object Model.

Comment: @JamesLove: feel free to post this answer. I feel you are right... calling the WS require a bit more work, but only a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using the [Business Connectivity Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee534979.aspx) instead? This is available in the SharePoint Foundation 2010. In SharePoint 2007, you would need the BDC and the corresponding licence.

Otherwise I would recommend using the [lists webservice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

I can see only pain and frustration coming from using the import, even if it did work.

In the case where you are able to run an stsadm command, I would recommend creating a powershell script to use the object model to make the changes.

The powershell script could then load an xml file for the list of changes needed.

Comment: BCS is not an option because I don't have access to the source directly... The lists webservice could be complex because it would require to write an intermediate apps (not very complex actually).

Comment: In the case you rights to run stsadm on the server, you can also go with a powershell script. It is easier to update a list through the object model and as intermediate apps go is quite lightweight development wise.

Answer (score 1):

You need GUIDs for key properties required for the object model to construct the elements to be written, when importing via `STSADM -o import`. This will be extremely long and tedious to do. You're far safer either drumming up an intermediate application using Lists Webservice, or the Client Object Model.